# python: Searching strings in one list in another list, then appending an entire list entry to a new list

Tags: python

Example:

```
L1=['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird', 'rabbit', 'horse']

L2=[('cat', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('cat', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('cat', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('fish', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('dog', 'w', 'x', 'y'), ('dog', 'z', 'y', 'x'), ('horse', '1', '2', '3'), ('monkey', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('kitten', 'h', 'i', 'j'), ('bird', '4', '5', '6')]
```

I am trying to search the strings in L1 in L2, so that if the string in L1 is present in any part of L2, the whole entry from L2 `"('cat, a, b, c')"` is appended to a new list.  I also thought that maybe removing the entries that do not have any part of a string from L1 would work. 
I tried:

```
def searcher(L1, L2):
    common = []
    for x in L1:
        if re.search(x, L2):
            common.append(L2)

    return common
```

but that didnt work.
The actual list I am using is much longer, so an efficient code would really help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the parentheses around the string in `L2`?  They don't do anything.

Comment: Or do you actually mean `('cat', 'a', 'b', 'c')` for the first entry of L2?

Comment: @marsx: What have you tried that doesn't work? Otherwise this is just a homework question.

Comment: I do actually mean ('cat', 'a', 'b', 'c'), sorry.

Comment: I tried:
def searcher(L1, L2):
    common = []
    for x in L1:
        if re.search(x, L2):
            common.append(L2)

    return common

Comment: If `L1 = ('pig', 'cat')` and `L2 = [('a, pig, jump'), ...]`, should `common` include `('a', 'pig', 'jump')`?

Comment: ya that's the idea, it should include all of the entries from L2 that I posted except the kitten and monkey ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
s = set(L1)
new_list = [a for a in L2 if any(b in s for b in a)]
```

Comment: @marsx: The solution was for the first version of your question.  Updated now.

Comment: actually, this works perfectly once you take out the .split part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
s = set(L1)
new_list = [a for a in L2 if s.intersection([w.strip() for w in set(a.split(","))])]
```