# Searching list using keywords from other list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have this list

```
some_list = [
    "red apple",
    "red banana",
    "house is green",
    "blue road",
    "blue hat"
]
```

I want to specify my keywords in another list.

```
search_strings = ["red", "green"]
```

Is there a way to get this end results without too much looping?

```
# search some_list using keywords from search_strings
red = ["red apple", "red bana"]
green = ["house is green"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[words for words in some_list if kw in words.split()] for kw in search_strings]
```

That gives you:

```
[['red apple', 'red banana'], ['house is green']]
```

Also, if the "sencences" in `some_list` or the length of `search_strings` get bigger, it might pay to convert them to sets (like `search_strings = set(search_strings)`).

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers in the following questions can be adapted to your purpose:
• [python: Searching strings in one list in another list then appending an entire list entry to a new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785403),
• [Search for any word or combination of words from one string in a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264163),
•  [How to search string members of a list in another string in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711963),
• [Remove list entries that match any entry in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559465),
• [Search a list of strings for any sub-string from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749342),
• [Python: search for strings listed in one file from another text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370342),
•  [If string does not contain any of list of strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611524)
The answers to those questions include various loop or list comprehension techniques (like in phg's answer to the current question) and also include `filter` illustrations you may find useful.